# How to Output Array with groupBy Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I am using the standard `groupBy` function, modified by returning `[hash]` instead of `hash`.  This returns an array of objects.

How can I instead output an array of arrays?

**Standard `groupBy` Function**

```
function groupBy(array, property) {
  var hash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!hash[array[i][property]]) hash[array[i][property]] = [];
    hash[array[i][property]].push(array[i]);
  }
  return [hash];
}
```

**Output**

```
[{key1:[array]}, {key2:[array]}, {key3:[array]}]
```

**Desired Output**

```
[[array1], [array2], [array3]]
```

Ultimately, I would like to run a for each over the output of arrays to pass into another function.

For instance,

```
let group = groupItemBy(cart, 'id');
console.log(group.length); // should be greater than 1 for multiple indexes
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid. Please check.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: `[key2:` is invalid JavaScript syntax. Either you want a plain object with named keys or an array. You cannot have some half-half.

Comment: Your `key` and `array` are separated by `:` which is not valid.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I updated the question.

Comment: `return [hash]` makes no sense. There is no benefit whatsoever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
return [hash];
```

Do:

```
return Object.values(hash);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to get this to work with nested data.  See: http://jsbin.com/cemedebugu/edit?js,console

Comment: That really is a different question, as there the property does not exist in the objects, but in nested objects. This will also mean you need to better define the function arguments so that it is clear where this property is to be located. If you cannot make it work as you expect, I would suggest posting that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you return `hash` and not `[hash]` , just get the objects values:

```
 Object.values(groupItemBy(cart, 'carrierId'))
```

Alternatively build up the hashtable and the result in parallel:

```
 function group(array, key){
   const hash = {}, result = [];

   for(const obj of array){
     if(hash[ obj[key] ]){
       hash[ obj[key] ].push(obj);
     } else {
       result.push( hash[ obj[key] ] = [obj]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I think OP function is returning an array.

Comment: I'm not seeing the difference between logging ```Object.values(groupItemBy(cart, 'carrierId'))``` and ```group```...

Comment: Not sure if it's causing problems, but I am actually sorting by a ```value```, so when I return ```hash``` and log ```Object...``` everything gets put into a single array.

Comment: @kvna what do you mean with *sorting by a value* ?

Comment: Would you please take a look at this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/04v1uczr/

Comment: Essentially I would like to convert a cart into multiple carts based on item id to pass in to another function for submission.

Comment: Yes, I renamed ```carrierId``` to make the fiddle more concise.  Edited the question to match.  Sorry for the typos.

Comment: In this case I'm looking to output ```[ [ { item1} ], [ {item2}, {item3} ] ]```.

Comment: @kvna `Object.values(groupBy(cart.map(el => el.item), "id"));`